# How can I raise a number to a power in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

How can I raise a number to a power in Delphi?

Comment: Try  [Delphi and the Power Function](http://dn.embarcadero.com/article/20026)

Comment: even a simple google search could tell you this.

Comment: So I had to implement it myself

Comment: @Diego. Which Delphi version are you using?

Comment: @Diego. Your question doesn't even contain a description of "this math function isn't included".

Comment: Even a google search for your exact question title brings up the answer

Comment: Holy Crap dude.  F1 key. Help files. Google.  Someone get this guy a clue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

in Delphi 4 and later, use the Power function from the math unit. In earlier versions, use the Pow function given below.

```
{** A power function from Jack Lyle. Said to be more powerful than the
Pow function that comes with Delphi. }
function Power2(Base, Exponent : Double) : Double;
{ raises the base to the exponent }
CONST
cTiny = 1e-15;

VAR
Power : Double; { Value before sign correction }

BEGIN
Power := 0;
{ Deal with the near zero special cases }
IF (Abs(Base) < cTiny) THEN BEGIN
  Base := 0.0;
END; { IF }
IF (Abs(Exponent) < cTiny) THEN BEGIN
  Exponent := 0.0;
END; { IF }

{ Deal with the exactly zero cases }
IF (Base = 0.0) THEN BEGIN
  Power := 0.0;
END; { IF }
IF (Exponent = 0.0) THEN BEGIN
  Power := 1.0;
END; { IF }

{ Cover everything else }
IF ((Base < 0) AND (Exponent < 0)) THEN
    Power := 1/Exp(-Exponent*Ln(-Base))
ELSE IF ((Base < 0) AND (Exponent >= 0)) THEN
    Power := Exp(Exponent*Ln(-Base))
ELSE IF ((Base > 0) AND (Exponent < 0)) THEN
    Power := 1/Exp(-Exponent*Ln(Base))
ELSE IF ((Base > 0) AND (Exponent >= 0)) THEN
    Power := Exp(Exponent*Ln(Base));

{ Correct the sign }
IF ((Base < 0) AND (Frac(Exponent/2.0) <> 0.0)) THEN
  Result := -Power
ELSE
  Result := Power;
END; { FUNCTION Pow }
```

Source:

Read more [here](http://dn.embarcadero.com/article/20026)

Comment: @Diego - Add it to your uses clause